# Video.JS works but with quirks when PHP used to restrict access to video

Tags: php, video.js

So what I have is a file, getVideo.php, which takes a get variable $id which corresponds to a specific video.  If I keep the video file in the web root and use that directly as the source, everything works great.

Now what I've done is put the videos outside of the web root, so that I can use getVideo.php to determine access privileges.  Assuming access is granted, the part of the code corresponding to the emitting of the video file in getVideo.php is

```
$filePath = VIDEOBASEURL.$guideData['video_url'];

if (file_exists($filePath)){
    //header('Content-Type: '.mime_content_type($filePath));
    header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filePath));
    readfile($filePath);
}
```

Now this does work fine, in that the video will play when getVideo.php?id=1 for example is used as the source.  The problem is, it becomes no longer possible to skip to arbitrary parts of the video.  In fact you can't jump anywhere in the video at all, whether it be forwards or backwards, and you can't even drag the progress meter.  All you can do is watch the video from start to finish.  I'm not really quite sure what I'm doing wrong that would cause this behavior.

The test file is in fact a .mp4 file, and when I link directly to its copy in the web root, everything works fine - just when it's going through the access controlled getVideo.php version, I can't skip around in the video.  Instead, clicking to skip ahead just pauses the video.

EDIT - This is actually independent of video.js.  Upon trying to watch the video directly from the getVideo.php file, so using whatever is built into Chrome/Firefox, the video is not jumpable even there.  So I'm guessing I'm returning the video file incorrectly in some way.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because you are trying to stream the video from a PHP file. Every time you request that PHP file, it must reread the mp4 file, rather than having the server return bytes at a specified point in the file. In the long run, this approach will probably not work, and you should look into just restricting access to the page with the video element.

Comment: How would I restrict access to an mp4 file based on for example, session variable values?  Basically all the video files would be in the same folder, but I'm not sure how I can authenticate access to the files.  I saw a way to use include files for authenticating access to php files, but I don't know about for mp4.

Comment: Basically I could restrict access to the page with the video, sure, but if I'm not keeping the video files outside of the webroot, it's still pretty simple to copy paste the video source and let it be visible to people who don't have access to the page with the video embedded, no?

Comment: It depends on just how adamant you are about how restricted you want the videos to be. Also, depending on who are watching your videos, they may or may not know how to find the URL of the video. I would just go with restricting access to the page.

Answer (score 1):

The key word for this topic is "byte range requests".

I think every browser today trys to load videos using a HTTP_RANGE in the HTTP header, telling the server to just send a specific part of the file. On mobile devices there is no other way to load videos into a webpage.
So you had to handle the range request yourself in PHP.
Sending the video this way you will have the ability to seek to any position in the video even if it is not already bufferd (not true for flash players!). 
On the quick I found this page. In "Appendix A: Streaming for Apple iPhone" you'll find a PHP script that you can easily extend to do permission checks.
[mobiforge.com/design-development/content-delivery-mobile-devices](http://mobiforge.com/design-development/content-delivery-mobile-devices)

I did not check the script but it looks good. I use the same approach may years on a video asset management system and it works with no problems. The PHP example above did not handle "multibyte range" requests but I think that does not matter for video. The only client I've found that use multibyte range requests is the adobe PDF reader plugin.

This approach is also good for any kind of downloads to allow the broswer to resume a download or Download-Manager plugins to download one file in many streams.

For the whole story see: [www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.1)

EDIT:
I just found an error in that PHP script:
In function rangeDownload() search for the line

```
if ($range0 == '-') {
```

and replace it with:

```
if ($range[0] == '-') {
```

There is also a problem if the browser do not send a HTTP_RANGE request.
In this case the script will use PHP readfile(). I think readfile() read the whole file into memory (at least it was true in the past). For video delivery to many users this is a serious issue. So do not use readfile() for big files. Instead send the file in chunks like in "// Start buffered download" at the end of the script.

I hope there are no other issues.